# Linear Algebra - question on the proof of the Replacement Theorem in Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm not quite fully understanding the author's use of induction to prove the replacement theorem in their book Linear Algebra:
[image]

The induction hypothesis is, as I understand it, that the theorem holds for some integer $m\geq0$. How does the author then assert from this that there exists a set $L=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_{m+1}\}$ with $m+1$ linearly independent vectors? The theorem is assumed to be true for $m$, so to me the set $L$ should have at most $m$ vectors, as there could be no guarantee that the vector space in question has dimension greater than $m$. In fact, what's trying to be proven is precisely that the theorem would also hold for $m+1$, which would then enable such an assertion. What's the logic behind this thought process? Thanks.

Comment: Similar if not same doubt was raised in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081390/doubt-in-the-use-of-induction-in-theorem-1-10-replacement-theorem-in-friedberg) and was resolved by OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set $L$ is no longer the same set stated in the induction hypothesis (with $m$ linearly independent vectors).

This is $L$ of step $m+1$. In this step, you're trying to prove that given a set $L$ with $m+1$ vectors, **you can come up with** some set $H$ wherein $\operatorname{span}(LUH)=V$. So, really, he isn't asserting anything (and, consequently, he isn't using circular reasoning); that statement is simply your starting 'condition', which you must show implies the desired result.

Also note that, in this (m + 1)th step, $n$ remains constant. That is, $V$ is still generated by the same set $G$, which has $n$ vectors (just clearing that up).